# Does WOP guarantee that if a countable set has a minimum, then it can be arranged to be monotonically increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I think this may be the case, and I've written a proof for it, but I'm not sure how rigorous it is.

Proof: Let S be a countable set, enumerated such that $$\forall x \in S, S=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}.$$ Then, by the well-ordered principle, if $$\exists x=min(S),$$ then S can be ordered to be monotnically increasing such trhat $$x_i \le x_{i+1} \forall x \in S.$$

This would imply that if a set has a minimum element then it can be ordered from least to greatest; and similarly would provide structure for proof that if a set has a maximum element then it can be ordered from greatest to least.

Answer (score 5):

This is not correct.  Consider the set $S$ of all nonnegative rational numbers.  This set is countable, since the set of rational numbers is countable.  And it has a minimum element, namely $0$.  But you can't list out the rationals in increasing order like $x_1<x_2<x_3<\dots$, because between any two rationals there is another rational.

It's hard to point out the flaw in your reasoning because it's hard to understand exactly what your reasoning is to begin with.  The well-ordering principle is a property of the ordering of the natural numbers.  Here you are considering some different set $S$ with a different ordering, so the well-ordering principle just doesn't tell you anything about it.  The well-ordering principle says that any nonempty set of natural numbers has a least element, but it doesn't mean that just because some other ordered set happens to have a least element, then that set must "look like" the natural numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't non-negative rationals be well ordered with respect to the order induced from $\mathbb{N}$? though that order will be quite different from standard ordering of rationals

Comment: @user160738: Well, the phrasing of the question was a bit unclear about what ordering they were talking about.  I assumed they were taking $S$ to already have an ordering (and they didn't want to change the order): otherwise, what does it mean to say that $\min(S)$ exists?  I think when OP says "$S$ can be ordered to be monotonically increasing" they are not literally talking about defining a new order relation but are rather using "order" to mean "enumerate", as in "list out in some order".

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: Perhaps a sequence would work better for this, but I meant that if I have a set with elements that, if there is a minimum, I can rearrange the elements in the set to be in increasing order. I see why it doesn't hold for the set of rationals itself but it could work for subsets of the set of real numbers.

Comment: @PeterClark: Well, it will work for _some_ countable ordered sets.  But it won't always work, as my example shows.  I don't know exactly what more you're asking for.

Comment: @EricWofsey with the rationals, however, there is no smallest rational number, so you can't find min(Q) and enumerate it.

Comment: @PeterClark: My example is the nonnegative rationals, not the rationals.  There is a smallest nonnegative rational.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using a stronger assumption than you stated: you seem to use "*every* (nonempty) subset of $S$ has a minimal element."

This does in fact imply that $S$ is well-ordered (unlike the nonnegative rationals); however, *it still doesn't help prove your claim*! This is because, when you build your listing by induction, you have no way to argue that it contains *every* element of $S$; all you can conclude is that you've monotonically listed *some* of $S$.

For an explicit example of this, consider the set $$S=\{1-{1\over 2^n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{3-{1\over 2^n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ It's not hard to show that every nonempty subset of $S$ has a least element; but the elements of $S$ can't be listed in increasing order. If you try your inductive construction, you get the listing $${1\over 2}, {3\over 4}, {7\over 8}, . . .$$ but e.g. ${5\over 2}$ never shows up here, even though it's in $S$.